# Failed to connect to mail server PHP

Tags: php, xampp

I just started learning PHP and am experimenting with the mail() function. I use XAMPP server to run the scripts and have a form which values should be emailed to me. However, once the form is submitted and is redirected to my php file I get an error

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Php files\woah\woah.php on line 13
```

This is my scripts from the HTML and PHP

woah.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="woah.php">
        <label for="Typed1">Type 1</label>
        <input type="text" name="Typed1"><br>
        <label for="Typed2">Type 2</label>
        <input type="text" name="Typed2"><br>
        <label for="submit">Submit form</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And from woah.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Yooo php</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
    $Type1=$_POST['Typed1'];
    $Type2=$_POST['Typed2'];

    $to='experimenting.Logan@gmail.com';
    $Message='Yo you typed '.$Type1. ' and also '. $Type2;

    mail($to,' ',$Message,'From: Yes');
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you install a mail server? I assume you are a windows user, and windows does not have one by default. Remember, `mail()` does not send email, it only passes it on to a real mail server

Comment: Isn't Mercury which is included in XAMPP server already a mail server

Comment: Dont see a reference to Mercury (whatever it is) in the list of what comes with XAMPP

Comment: Also `'From: Yes'` I dont think many modern email servers would send that anywhere, and none would accept it as incoming mail.Most now insist that the from address is a valid email address on the transmitting server (anti spam and all that)